# Create a new series with same index

Tags: python

I have a series with the following

```
2     [2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 5, 8, 7, 1, 2, 1, 0, 8, 4, ...
5                                          [3, 1, 5, 0]
8     [9, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 6, 1, 7, 0, 1, 4, 6, 1, 3, ...
9               [1, 1, 0, 8, 0, 0, 2, 9, 8, 6, 0, 3, 0]
11    [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 8, 7, 5, 7, 5, ...
```

I want to create a new series that keeps the index (2, 5, 8, 9, 11),  with values equal to the length of the list in each row

The result would be

```
2   25
5   4
8   20
9   13
11  18
```

Comment: What datatype is your "series"? Are these Pandas series?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what the problem is, what you expected, what you got, and any traceback.

Comment: Pandas series of lists of integers

Answer (score 1):

```
list(map(lambda x: (x, len(object[x])), indices))
```

Its somewhat pseudo code because you haven't specified your data type or variable names, but the general approach is that you have an object of data indexed by some index `x`. So loop over all the `x`s and obtain the length property of the resultant data structure.

Edit: since you stated it was pandas Series of integer lists try this:

```
import pandas as pd
S = pd.Series([[1,2,3], [2,3]], index=[2,4])
print(S)
# 2    [1, 2, 3]
# 4       [2, 3]
lengths = list(map(lambda x: len(S[x]), S.index))
S2 = pd.Series(lengths, index=S.index)
print(S2)
# 2    3
# 4    2
```